# GIS through Games: Ideas or Links

Tags: qgis, geography, references

I'm managing a project - http://nepanode.anl.gov aimed at improving data awareness and sharing around Environmental impact analysis. I'm struggling to come up with ways to engage users and show them how they can apply the site. I'm looking for specific ideas, games, demos, tutorials to demonstrate how the site can be used; looking for new ideas and/or links to existing training resources that aim to engage users through games or case studies? Limited to users only using the site and/or using QGIS

Comment: I have added a link in the answers below which may spark some ideas for you.  Also, having worked in the computer games industry I have links with games/UI designers and coders.  I would love to explore possibilities for involvement with your project but this is obviously not the appropriate forum, so please PM me using the email in my profile to take such a discussion off-line.

Comment: not sure this will even work as a community Wiki. Seems too broad to meet requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [one example](http://www.macaulay.ac.uk/resources/Pipe-Dreams2.swf) from the John Hutton Institute in Aberdeen (formerly The Macaulay Institute - where I headed up their commercial GIS team, though didn't create this game), Scotland, which might provide some ideas.